# Calculate number for each row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My table structure is below:

```
CREATE TABLE [ACC].[Document](
    [DocumentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [Number] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ConfirmStatusEnumID] [int] NULL,
    [SignedPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentID] ASC
)
```

I want to set Number column value automaticaly increment number started from 1 for each SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID column. In other word if new record inserted in this table, value of Number column calculated in instead of trigger, such as below:

```
 ISNULL( (Select Max(A.Number) 
          From Acc.Document A
          Where A.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID = Inserted.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID),1)
```

What is the best practices for this problem.

Comment: Why `instead of` trigger?

Comment: @dezso Why does everyone think `instead of` triggers are evil? Are you suggesting an after trigger is better? Do you think it's better to insert a row and then update the value, rather than just insert the intact row once? Do you think it's better to perform business logic and validation *after* you've inserted the row, so if validation fails you have to do the work twice (insert and then rollback) instead of zero times?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - No, no and no.  I use `AFTER` triggers only for modifyling _other_ tables based on the row in question.  The problem is apparently in my box so to say - `INSTEAD OF` triggers can be defined only on views in Oracle an PostgreSQL, and there are `BEFORE` triggers for doing things like the OP wants to accomplish.  So +1 for your comment, because I was unaware of this difference between RDBMSes.

Comment: @dezso there are no BEFORE triggers in SQL Server. [We've been asking for them for a long time](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/361223/add-before-triggers-not-the-least-for-ddl-statements) (especially for DDL) but sadly they're not buying in.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to store this value in the `Number` column? Much better to derive this information at query time than to bother storing redundant information and constantly have to update it as rows are added, changed or deleted.

```
SELECT DocumentID, SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID, 
  Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID
    ORDER BY DocumentID)
FROM ACC.Document;
```

Comment: Sometimes, a number put on a document is a reference number that users refer to, it is printed on the hardcopy, for instance a should never change

Comment: @Alireza but a number that users refer to that is only valid in combination with SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID (since 1 will be re-used for every distinct SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID)? Seems DocumentID would make more sense for the purpose you describe... that's unique, at least, and by definition will not change.

Comment: Consider a software being used by Accountants of multiple companies, in multiple financial years, they expect their Number field to increase sequentially without interrupt in their own domain, not to jump from 1 to 17.
Also, it is usually advised not to use the primary key in any interaction with the user, and while I can't explain why, my experiences in software development/architecture strongly verify this.